# Стандартные библиотеки С++

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток гуру С++ и не только. Начал изучать этот замечательный язык по книге 2016 <strike>, но, как оказывается, некоторые примеры не совсем работают. Есть пример возведения в квадрат числа с помощью функции `square()`, но MSVS ругается на неопределенность идентификатора.</strike> Возникли вопросы:

<strike>1. почему `square()` не работает?</strike>
2. где можно посмотреть описание стандартных библиотек С++(возможно есть аналог docs.oracle.com)?
3. можно ли в MSVS переходить в код функций, библиотек и т.д как это делается в том же IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/  Вопрос у вас странноватый. Вы бы показали весь код примера, далеко не у всех есть книга под названием "2016" :) Скорее всего, вы просто что-то не так перенесли из книги...

Comment: название книги не писал потому что не хочу делать рекламу(антирекламу),а пример достаточно тривиален чтобы сделать в нём ошибку.

Comment: перешел по вашей ссылке и не нашел там описание функции square, хотя sqrt нашлась без проблем. Возможно функции square устарела??

Comment: Да вроде никогда такой стандартной функции не было. Думаю, она написана автором книги, посмотрите внимательно.

Comment: думаю вы правы, в начале книги автор подключал собственную библиотеку. вопрос номер 1 автоматически отпадает.

Answer (score 2):

На сайте С++ reference .
http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream . 
Название того, что нужно найти, библиотеки и не только, нужно забить в поисковой строке.

Comment: Почему ссылка именно на `basic_fstream`?

Comment: Я указываю путь. Если кому-то нужно что-то конкретное, может искать другое.

Comment: Ведь fstream - одна из библиотек, и я указала её, как образец.

Comment: Хотя вы правы. basic_fstream - это не библиотека, а класс ввода-вывода. Но не судите строго, я новичок.